# Behavior of temporal tables in SQL transactions

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions, temporal

We have a scenario, where we are we are doing multiple operations inside a SQL transaction. Sequence of steps done (in order):-

1. Create a "Customer" table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
   (
      ID   INT              PRIMARY KEY (ID),
      NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
      AGE  INT              ,     
   );
   ```
2. We turned on system_versioning on this table.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS

   ADD  VALIDFROM DATETIME2(2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERS_VALIDFROM DEFAULT '1900.01.01 00:00:00.00', 

   VALIDTO   DATETIME2(2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL  CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERS_VALIDTO DEFAULT '9999.12.31 23:59:59.99', 

   PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (VALIDFROM, VALIDTO);
   ```
3. Insert 1 record in CUSTOMERS table.

   ```
   INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES(1, 'JOHN', 10)
   ```
4. Update this record.

   ```
   UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET NAME = 'JOHN1' where ID = 1
   ```
5. So far so good, we get the history in the temporal table, when we query.

[Select on temporal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZwkx.png)

6. Now we run a transaction, and in that transaction, we do an update and then a delete.

   ```
   BEGIN TRANSACTION TemporalDelete  
   GO  
   USE KJ1;  
   GO  
   update CUSTOMERS set NAME = 'Hemant2' where ID = 1
   Go
   DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS
       WHERE ID = 1;  
   GO  
   COMMIT TRANSACTION TemporalDelete;  
   GO
   ```
7. Ideally we should get 3 records in temporal table, but we get only 2. We miss the update that happens inside the transaction.
8. If we run this update - then - delete, without a transaction, we get 3 records as usual.

We are querying the history table using this statement

`SELECT *, VALIDTO, VALIDFROM FROM CUSTOMERS FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL`

Are we missing something?

How do we get the actual changes all records went through, irrespective of the whether it is in a transaction or not?

Comment: How are you querying the history? Are you directly querying the history table or using `FOR SYSTEM_TIME` based queries?

Comment: Yes, we are querying the history using `FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL`.

Comment: [How do I query temporal data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables#how-do-i-query-temporal-data): "FOR SYSTEM_TIME filters out rows that have period of validity with zero duration (SysStartTime = SysEndTime).
Those rows will be generated if you perform multiple updates on the same primary key within the same transaction.
...
If you need to include those rows in the analysis, query the history table directly."

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves our problem. Please post this as an answer.